# Java Stream code improvement

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a map of cars `Map<String, List<Car>>` which can be returned by `getCarsMap()` method where key is model of car , and value is list of cars of same model.

I would like to improve `Car addCar(Car car)` function. For now I wrote this a bit ugly peace of code

```
public Car addCar(Car car) {
    if(getCarsMap().entrySet().stream().anyMatch(es -> es.getKey().equals(car.getModel()))){
        if(!getCarsMap().get(car.getModel()).contains(car)){
            getCarsMap().get(car.getModel()).add(car);
        }
    }else{
        List<Car> tmpList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        tmpList.add(car);
        getCarsMap().put(car.getModel(), tmpList) ;
    }
    return car;
}
```

Also, need to write something similar for `removeCar(Car car)` but hope it's gonna be easier with some nice addCar method as a template.

Comment: post that question here too  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ No. Don't suggest Crossposting. Btw: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Comment: `if(getCarsMap().entrySet().stream().anyMatch(es -> es.getKey().equals(car.getModel())))` This is just a worse way to write `getCarsMap().containsKey(car.getModel())`. Why do you use a `List` if you don't want duplicates? And why do you use `getBoatsMap()` in the `else` block?

Comment: yeah, I'm a beginner that is why :) ok, this list is wrong, I'll use Set. And getBoatsMap() is getCarsMap()....sorry

Answer (score 1):

My idea - rely on compute [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) of Map.

So my method `populateMapWith` process current map according to your case:

- if value list is empty - create new one, add element, add to map
- if present, just add element to current list

as well as `removeFromMap` according to removing.

I illustrated it with Object class, just to simplify the case

```
public class BaseTest {

    private Map<String, List<Object>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        Object car1 = new Object() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "car1";
            }
        };

        Object car2 = new Object() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "car1";
            }
        };

        populateMap(car1);
        populateMap(car2);

        assertEquals(2, myMap.get("car1").size());

        removeFromMap(car2);

        assertEquals(1, myMap.get("car1").size());
    }

    private void populateMap(Object o) {
        myMap.computeIfAbsent(o.toString(), key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(o);
    }

    private void removeFromMap(Object o) {
        myMap.computeIfPresent(o.toString(), (key,list) -> { list.remove(o); return list;});
    }
}
```

UPD : improved methods after discussion with [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

Comment: Note the existence if the specialized `compute…` methods, for adding: `myMap.computeIfAbsent(o.toString(), key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(o);` and for removing: `myMap.computeIfPresent(o.toString(), (key,list) -> { list.remove(o); return list;});` or if you want to clean up empty lists: `myMap.computeIfPresent(o.toString(), (key,list) -> {list.remove(o); return list.isEmpty()? null: list;});`

Comment: @Holger yep, i've checked this two methods, but it is the case  - we don't know `absent` or `present`, so i've decided use more general method `compute` that covers two case at the time

Comment: Apparently, you didn’t get the logic. You don’t have to know whether the key is absent or present as these methods will do the right thing for your. For the `populateMapWith` case, you can use `computeIfAbsent(X, key -> new ArrayList<>())` which will either return the existing `List` or store a new one and return it; in either case, it will return the right list to `add` to. For `removeFromMap`, the case is even simpler, you can use `computeIfPresent`, because if the key is absent, there is nothing to do.

Comment: @Holger many thank! i just figured out the point! your approach much more elegant. i check this methods at the beginning but looks like i have to pay attention to it. i've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if(!getCarsMap().get(car.getModel()).contains(car))
> ```

It seems that you do not wish to have duplicates. So instead of a List, you must use a Set, that does not add duplicate elements, like:

```
Map<String, Set<Car>> carmap = getCarsMap();
```

> `getBoatsMap().put(car.getModel(), tmpList) ;`

This doesn't make sense. Putting a car in a map that is supposed to have boats is bewildering. However, I assume to go with it.

So we can have:

```
Set<Cars> tempcar = new HashSet<>();
tempcar.add(car);
getBoatsMap().put(car.getModel(),tempcar);
```

> `public Car addCar(Car car)`

The return type of addCar method. A method returns the object that it manipulates. Here, the map is manipulated and not the object. It should be something like:

```
public Map<String,Set<Car>> addCar(Car car)
```

So we can have the following code:

```
 public HashMap<String,Set<Car>> addCar(Car car){
        Map<String, Set<Car>> carmap = getCarsMap();
        if(carmap.containsKey(car.getModel())){
            HashSet<Car> carset = carmap.get(car.getModel());
            carset.add(car);
            map.put(car.getModel(),carset);
        }else{
            carmap = getBoatsMap();
            Set<Cars> tempcar = new HashSet<>();
            tempcar.add(car);
            carmap.put(car.getModel(),tempcar);
        }
        return carmap;
   }
```

This can be the basic template for you to move on. However, this also can be further optimized. A deeper study of Java Collections API and Java 8 can provide you with better ideas.

For, removeCar(), the method signature can be:

```
public Car removeCar(Car)
```

**UPDATE**
I see in comment that `getBoatsMap()` is a mistake.
So the code is:

```
public Map<String, Set<Car>> addCar(Car car){
    Map<String, Set<Car>> carmap = getCarsMap();
    if(carmap.containsKey(car.getModel())){
        HashSet<Car> carset = carmap.get(car.getModel());
        carset.add(car);
        map.put(car.getModel(),carset);
    }else{
        Set<Cars> tempcar = new HashSet<>();
        tempcar.add(car);
        carmap.put(car.getModel(),tempcar);
    }
    return carmap;
}
```

Comment: You should make up your mind ... either use `HashMap<String,Set<Car>>` or `Map<String, HashSet<Car>>` (or even better `Map<String, Set<Car>>`), but both together doesn't work.

Comment: You don’t need to re-`put` a mapping that’s already in the map. Further `.add(car)` is common code, executed in both cases. So the improved code is `HashSet<Car> carset=carmap.get(car.getModel() ); if(carset==null) { carmap.put(car.getModel(),carset=new HashSet<>()); } carset.add(car);`. Now, if you are at this point, you can improve it using the might of Java 8: `carmap.computeIfAbsent(car.getModel(), key -> new HashSet<>()).add(car);` which has the same logic, but is a one-liner…

Answer (score 1):

The tips:

- Use `Set` instead of `List` because `Set` doesn't allow duplicates.
- Use `contains` to check if an element is in a collection, regardless of
  whether it's a `List` or a `Set`. (`Car` class must have a `equals` method that compares the field values.)
- Return a `boolean` to indicate if the collection was modified as a
  result of the operation. This is what Java collections do.

The code:

```
public boolean addCar(Car car) {
    Map<String, Set<Car>> carsMap = getCarsMap();
    if (!carsMap.containsKey(car.getModel())) {
        carsMap.put(car.getModel(), new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(car)));
        return true;
    }
    if (!carsMap.get(car.getModel()).contains(car)) {
        return carsMap.get(car.getModel()).add(car);
    }
    return false;
}
```